# Компилятор Keil uvision 5 ругается на union

Tags: компилятор, объединение, union

для удобства нужно использовать объедение union, но компилятор ругается, пробовал добавлять #pragma pack(n)  (n-количество байт), но не помогло, как решить проблему, в IAR с этим проблем не было. Кусок кода представлен ниже, заранее спасибо!!!

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t ID;
    uint8_t DLC;
    union
    {
        uint8_t data[8];
        struct{
            uint32_t data32[2];
        };
    };  
}CanMsg;
```

Comment: Забыл добавить, код на СИ для ARM

Comment: ../Core/Inc/CAN.h(15): error:  #3093: anonymous structs are only supported in --gnu mode, or when enabled with #pragma anon_unions
    };
../Core/Inc/CAN.h(16): error:  #3092: anonymous unions are only supported in --gnu mode, or when enabled with #pragma anon_unions
   };

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, ответ на вопрос приведен в тексте ошибки - C не позволяет создавать `union` без имен, это расширение gnu. Или включайте расширение, или придумывайте имена.